# zend 2: How to hookup Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable to Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework2

[The examples I have seen](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.dbtable.html) using Zend\Authentication instantiate a DbAdapter pointing to a database. But I want to pass it my table gateway model instead. Is this possible or am I misunderstanding something?

I have this setup in my Module.php:

```
    'MyModule\Model\UserTable' => function($sm) {
        $tableGateway = $sm->get('UserTableGateway');
        $table = new UserTable($tableGateway);
        return $table;
    },
    'UserTableGateway' => function($sm) {
        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(
            new User());
        return new TableGateway('view_users', $dbAdapter, null,
            $resultSetPrototype);
    },
),
```

And now in the controller action I'd like to do something like this:

```
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;
...
$authAdapter = new AuthAdapter(**$this->getUserTable()->getAdapter()**);
$authAdapter
    ->setTableName('users')
    ->setIdentityColumn('username')
    ->setCredentialColumn('password')
```

How can I integrate my TableGateway Model with Zend\Authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

First - you should have the below code in config/autoload/global.php (or some other file)

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
),
```

Second - in the controller action -

```
$dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

// create auth adapter
$authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter);

// configure auth adapter
$authAdapter->setTableName('users')
        ->setIdentityColumn('username')
        ->setCredentialColumn('password');
```